# how to define a wifi password on D-Link DAP-1360

Tags: wireless-router

I have a D-Link DAP-1360 wifi repeater device and I wish to connect to it directly in order to define the wifi password (comes open by default).
I connect it directly to my PC with a network cable, but cannot seem to find its internal IP in order to connect to its admin console.
I also tried to connect it to the PC this way on one end and to the internet router/modem on the other, but nothing here also.
I found some documentation and forum content about it online, but all the information there (some "default" or standard internal IP addresses) didn't help me with my device.
How do I know its internal IP address for accessing its admin console and what do I need to connect exactly with the cables and such?

Comment: Does your computer get an IP address when connected?

Comment: You have to figure out a way to factory-reset the AP. How to do this should be on the user's guide.

Comment: 192.168.0.50 is the ip address. maybe the problem is your laptop ip address is in different range. open your adapter, set static ip address such as 192.168.0.1 to be same range. did it help?

Comment: With the router connected, Open a command prompt and do an "ipconfig" command, then look at the default gateway ip, this is your routers ip.

Comment: I've tried 192.168.0.50, I've reset the device and in the default gateway information I got 10.0.0.138, but that didn't get me nothing also. I don't know what the heck is wrong here...

Comment: @Botmaster Thanks your comment worked for me.